# Looping through visible rows only not working

Tags: excel, vba, loops, nested-loops

I am trying to write a piece of code, that will color all requests which contain only one unique name for each request. Why looping trough visible cells only is not working?

**UPDATE:**
I need to delete rows if there is only one name assigned to a particular request

So for below request I would like to remove Mary H (since her name appears only once in the request)

```
Request Number  Client Contact Assignee: Full Name
4350257 Eleanor B
4350257 Eleanor B
4350257 Mary H
```

This request is ok, no need to delete anything

```
8620428 Kevin M
8620428 Kevin M
```

In this request I would like to remove Mary H and Julia K since there names appears only once in the request)

```
7208497 Michael W
7208497 Mary H
7208497 Michael W
7208497 Julia K
```

My CODE:

```
Sub Testing()

Sheet1.Select

Dim r As Long, LR As Long
Dim ReqNo As Long, CCFullName As Long
Dim rgn2 As Range

LR = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'Request Number
ReqNo = Application.Match("Request Number", Sheet1.Rows(1), 0)
'Client Contact Assignee: Full Name
CCFullName = Application.Match("Client Contact Assignee: Full Name", Sheet1.Rows(1), 0)

Set rgn2 = Columns(CCFullName)

Dim cl As Range, rng As Range, x As Long

Set rng = Range("A2:A100")
Dim cell As Range

With Range("A2:A100").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
   For x = .Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
       Set cell = Range("A" & x) ' this sets the current cell in the loop
            For Each cl In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                For r = LR To 2 Step -1
                    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rgn2, Cells(r, CCFullName).Value) = 1 Then
                        Rows(r).Interior.Color = rgbBlueViolet
                    End If
                Next r
        Next cl
    Next x
End With
End Sub
```

The code above only colors names that are unique for the whole document, which is Mary H, Anna W and Thomas Y. However, I need the code to include also the 3 below names which occur once only in a particular request. (This is just a sample)

```
7208497 Kevin M
7208497 Julia K
8138382 Shahida B
```

Sample data:

```
Request Number  Client Contact Assignee: Full Name
4350257 Eleanor B
4350257 Eleanor B
4350257 Mary H
8620428 Kevin M
8620428 Kevin M
7208497 Michael W
7208497 Kevin M
7208497 Michael W
7208497 Julia K
7191212 Thomas Y
7191212 Shahida B
7191212 Shahida B
7191212 Shahida B
8138382 Julia K
8138382 Julia K
8138382 Shahida B
8138382 Julia K
8138382 Anna W
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code. It follows your updated, better description of your requirement.

```
Sub DeleteNonDuplicates()

    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Cnt As Long
    Dim R As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Sheet1
        R = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(R, "A"))
        For R = R To 2 Step -1
            Cnt = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Rng, .Cells(R, "A").Value, _
                                                         Rng.Offset(0, 1), .Cells(R, "B").Value)
            If Cnt = 1 Then
                .Rows(R).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next R
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

To pre-test the result on your sample enter the formula below in a blank column and copy down.

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$19,$A2,$B$2:$B$19,$B2)
```

The code applies exactly this formula and then deletes all rows where the count = 1.

Answer (score 0):

It is not working for visible cells because you are checking the count against `Set rgn2 = Columns(CCFullName)` entire column instead of Visible Cells only.

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rgn2, Cells(r, CCFullName).Value) = 1
```

For `rgn2` also you should use `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`. But this will not work for `Columns`, So you will have to use `Range`.

```
Set rgn2 = Range("B2:B19").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code can't do what you say it does. I took a guess at what you want and wrote the appended code for you. It must be pasted into the code module of your `Sheet1` worksheet. It's an event procedure and the correct location is critical. If pasted elsewhere it will not work.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim ReqNo As Long
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim C As Long

    ' skip if more than one cell was selected
    If Target.Cells.CountLarge = 1 Then
        Set Rng = Range(Cells(2, "A"), Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))

        If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Rng) Is Nothing Then
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            ReqNo = Target.Value
            C = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            With Rng
                Set Rng = .Resize(.Rows.Count, Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column)
            End With
            With Rng.Resize(Rng.Rows.Count, C)
                .Interior.Pattern = xlNone           ' remove existing coloring
                .Font.Color = 0
            End With

            For Each Cell In Rng
                With Cell
                    If .Value = ReqNo Then
                        .Resize(1, C).Interior.Color = rgbBlueViolet
                        .Resize(1, C).Font.Color = xlAutomatic
                    End If
                End With
            Next Cell
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Look for this line of code in the above procedure. `Set Rng = Range(Cells(2, "A"), Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))`. It specifies that the *Request Number* should be in column A. If you move it to another column you can change it here. Likewise, this line specifies that only items from row 2 and below should be considered. You can change that here if necessary.

Look for the line `C = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column`. It specifies that row 1, meaning the caption row, is where you take the measure for the width of your table. you can specify another row here.

The code takes action if you click on a *Request Number*. It will color all rows with  that same number violet. Since the chosen background color is dark it will change the font color to white.

I hope this code is useful to you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, what I need now is a little bit different. When using your code now - when I click on a cell, it highlights all rows with the same request number. That's great. But now, I need to highlight (first highlight, and then delete if I finally find the right solution) only rows which contain one unique name. For example, here it should highlight only Thomas Y and Mary H. /// 7191212 Thomas Y
7191212 Shahida B
7191212 Shahida B
7191212 Mary H

Comment: I don't follow your workflow but let's presume you clicked 7191212. How about clicking on any of the highlighted names (perhaps double-click is safer) to delete that row? Disallow deletion of the last highlighted row. If you want an unassisted deletion of rows there should be a criterium in the row itself by which it can be identified as being redundant.

Comment: In my original code I wanted to color the rows just to see if my code is working. But the idea is to remove such rows from the sheet. The rows where only one name is assigned to a given request.

Comment: Can you repeat that in slow motion? Every line in your list shows one name assigned to one request. Do you wish to remove duplicate assignments, leaving one for each request? If so, does it matter which one is left standing? Is this, in fact just a cleaning operation where coloring is unwanted and no individual selection by the user intended?